# CalendarView show minimum date as today

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to show `calendarView` that will set the minimum date as today for booking purposes. But in my code it will show the whole month and here I can book the previous date. So, I need a solution that will show dates available from today and can not select previous days.

How can I do this?

My code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE,Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE));
long date = calendar.getTime().getTime();
calendar_view.setMinDate(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. You need to set  current date to the calendar minimum date.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendarView.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the minimum date Max date"* (seems incomprehensible)? (Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58747667/edit), not here in comments (as appropriate).)